# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazon.android.Kiwi

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I am making app for Amazon Fire tablets. I am getting this error. Please help me to sort out this error. Thanks!`

```
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.amazon.android.Kiwi
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at com.smartdevs.playtube.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4635)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1999)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2060)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1181)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4558)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-26 00:16:59.470: E/AndroidRuntime(29646):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 00:16:59.595: W/ActivityManager(209):   Force finishing activity com.smartdevs.playtube/.Activities.MainActivity
04-26 00:16:59.595: V/ActivityStack(209): Prepare close transition: finishing ActivityRecord{41e6af50 com.smartdevs.playtube/.Activities.MainActivity}
04-26 00:16:59.681: D/dalvikvm(209): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1738K, 30% free 20462K/28935K, paused 3ms+7ms`
```

Comment: Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

This error is happening if you have  multidex enabled. for resolving this error you will have to do some changes.

1) Create a file name multidex.keep in App root folder.

2) Write com/amazon/android/Kiwi.class in that file.

3) Open app's build.gradle file and write below code in android tag.

```
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
    additionalParameters = ["--set-max-idx-number=55000"] // default 60000
}
```

4) Open app build.gradle file and inside android tag write

```
afterEvaluate {
if (!android.applicationVariants.matching { it.flavorName == 'mobile' }.isEmpty()) {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex' // enable multidex
        dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
    }
}
```

}